# Calculate time difference in milliseconds from a value i got using a formula in excel

Tags: excel

So I'm using the MID value to get the time out of the string, since my excel is in German the command is:

```
=TEIL(A2;11;13)
```

from

```
2022-09-08 11:50:16,765 INFO
```

Which leaves me with

```
11:50:16,765
```

I get the second time value in the same way. I have tried splitting the seconds and milliseconds by both . [DOTS] & , [COMMAS].

After I want to calculate the time difference I subtract the higher value (second time) from the lower one (first time), although my result is

> #WERT! (#VALUE!).

I have looked up for solutions already and figured out that for the German region I should use the time format hh:mm:ss,000 instead of hh:mm:ss.000 [COMMA instead of DOT]. Used this in all 3 cells (B2, C2 & D2 etc.).

Since it didn't work, I´ve tried to simply write some values in milliseconds as a text and divide them using the German time format and it worked (see columns E & F).

So my conclusion is that I am not able to subtract the values from each other because I am getting them from a formula? (Please correct me if I am wrong).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `11;13` in you mid you are capturing the leading space and this is causing Excel not to be able to convert the string to a true time.

Either TRIM the results in the subtraction:

```
=TRIM(C2)-TRIM(B2)
```

Or better yet, grab just the numbers without the spaces:

```
=MID(A2,12,12)
```

or in German:

```
=TEIL(A2;12;12)
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! Thanks. Although only for the first row for osme reason, I guess I am still having a newbie mistake somewhere since the others aint updating, although I updated the formulas on each of them `=MID(A3,12,12)`etc

Comment: Only you can figure it out.  copy paste the just the value from the result and see if there are any other unprintable characters that is causing an issue.  This is not something we are going to be able to help with directly because we do not have access to your data.

Comment: The issue was that the data source which I am using is in Linux and splitting the milliseconds with a comma, while i have to use a dot. I only replaced comma for a dot in the first few values though.

Thanks a lot Scott for the help in excel and checking on my grammar. Will take more care of it from now on!